# JSP foreach output

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I have a problem with foreach output in JSP netbeans.

```
<tr>
    <td>Dan od:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="danOd">
            <c:forEach begin="1" end="31" step="1" var="i">
                <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="mesecOd">
            <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="12" step="1">
                <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="godinaOd">
            <c:forEach begin=2010" end="2020" step="1" var="i">
                <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is part of the JSP page I am trying to output. I want to output 1-31 in first option, 1-12 in second and 2010-2020 in third, but this is what I get and I dont understand why.

I tried to find the answer but nothing helped, everything seems right to me. Here is the link of the image of my output.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/166c4.png]

Thanks in advance

[inspect element pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5POjl.png)

Sourced file to browser:

```
                    <select name="danOd">
                        <c:forEach begin="1" end="31" step="1" var="i">
                            <option value=""></option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
```

In the sourced file there is nothing in the value of the option, why? And thanks for this

Comment: your code looks fine, see the page in an actual browser it should work, it could be your netbeans it not showing correctly.

Comment: i am looking in chrome, nothing is showing on option dropdowns

Comment: And in the web developer ? What is the html of the select ? does it contains `option` ?

Comment: It contains option tag but doesnt contain elements of an option tag(nothing in dropdown) @AxelH

Comment: @AxelH I put the picture in the question

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand what should i send? You mean the whole JSP page html code? Sorry, i am begginer in this servlets and jsp and stuff @AxelH

Comment: Ive edited the question once again, check it out now @AxelH

Comment: I am using glassfish server...
@AxelH

Comment: Yes, on localhost, i see that it didnt execute it, but how should i make it work? Should i include some library or something @AxelH

Comment: @VeljkoMarkovic You've did add the `taglib` to use the jstl ?

Comment: No i dont know what that is @AxelH

Comment: @VeljkoMarkovic, this would have been much faster if you had tell us this was the first time you used JSTL. See my edited answers to see what you are missing.

Comment: Ive put that and now i have http status 500 error when i go to that jsp page @AxelH

Comment: @VeljkoMarkovic Follow a simple Tutorial to use JSTL, this would be easier than trying to explain that here. You don't have the rep to access the chat so this will be really long to explain. Just Google `JSTL tutorial` to find how to use it. There is a jar (thought this would be on glassfish ...) that need to be downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your last `select`

```
<c:forEach begin=2010" end="2020" step="1" var="i">
    <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

You are missing one `"`

```
<c:forEach begin="2010" end="2020" step="1" var="i">
    <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

This will compile and work with that correction.

EDIT :

To use the Jstl core, you need to add it to the JSP page with a specific tag, the `taglib`. This should be at the top of the file. After the `<%@page contentType... %>`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Without this, the server doesn't recognize the tags an skip them (see like HTML tags) and ends up in the client side.

Comment: thanks, but still the same output...when i open the option nothing appears -.-

Comment: @VeljkoMarkovic I have test this (without the table) and I have a result, check on a browser, if this is not working, check that the JSTL Core is present (should tell you but ...) by simply using `<c:out ...` somewhere in the page

Comment: <c:out works, i really dont understand what is happening, on every option dropdown nothing appears, just blank, its like i didnt put anything in option tag but thats not the case
@AxelH

Comment: @VeljkoMarkovic Do two test, one by removing the `select` from the `table`,just put then directly in the body, the second is to create a `select` yourself (with 2 or 3 option)  and see the results. This doesn't come from your `<c:forEach`. And in the sourceCode (result in HTML), what is the select look like ?

Comment: when i put this:
 <select name="danOd">
                            
                                <option>qmiql</option>
                                <option>qmiq2l</option>
                                <option>qmi3ql</option>
                            
                        </select>
everything loks fine and select is showing my dropdown. Its some problem in the foreach directive or some tags (var, begin, end, step)
@AxelH

Comment: @VeljkoMarkovic No, the code is correct, it's working one my test project. Check what is the result in the browser ( I mean the source code in the browser)... maybe you made a typo and only are missing one thing.